# Invalid grant error for free Office accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Are free Office accounts supported by Azure AD?

I've tried authenticating with two different accounts, one that has a monthly Office 365 subscription, and another free account that I created today.

I also have set up Microsoft sample users, and these are all working fine. But whenever I try to log into Outlook or OneDrive from my integration with either of the two accounts I mentioned above, authentication fails.

I can't find anything in the documentation that explains which types of accounts are not supported.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE**

On logging in with both accounts, these are the results:

**Account with monthly subscription:**

*Auth code:* M.R3_BAY.c531716c-c315-0c1e-7113-8805ab255856

*Error message:*

```
    array(7) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(13) "invalid_grant"
  ["error_description"]=>
  string(199) "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.
  Trace ID: 2e92a737-9d9a-4f2f-bbd1-17d231c5d701
  Correlation ID: e6ca5e4a-2a62-4a6d-a556-9a1de111d41d
  Timestamp: 2020-11-30 23:16:41Z"
  ["error_codes"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(9002313)
  }
  ["timestamp"]=>
  string(20) "2020-11-30 23:16:41Z"
  ["trace_id"]=>
  string(36) "2e92a737-9d9a-4f2f-bbd1-17d231c5d701"
  ["correlation_id"]=>
  string(36) "e6ca5e4a-2a62-4a6d-a556-9a1de111d41d"
  ["error_uri"]=>
  string(52) "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}
```

**Free account:**

*Auth code:* M.R3_BAY.6a128cd9-cb99-ee82-eafd-2934f94aa739

*Error message:*

```
    array(7) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(13) "invalid_grant"
  ["error_description"]=>
  string(199) "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.
  Trace ID: 285534b9-2f12-43ba-9af5-6aecf8d12302
  Correlation ID: 66e71cee-aee8-42e9-8744-c470a6037767
  Timestamp: 2020-11-30 23:17:02Z"
  ["error_codes"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(9002313)
  }
  ["timestamp"]=>
  string(20) "2020-11-30 23:17:02Z"
  ["trace_id"]=>
  string(36) "285534b9-2f12-43ba-9af5-6aecf8d12302"
  ["correlation_id"]=>
  string(36) "66e71cee-aee8-42e9-8744-c470a6037767"
  ["error_uri"]=>
  string(52) "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}
```

***UPDATE 2**

This is the request:

```
$postUrl = "/common/oauth2/token";
$hostname = "login.microsoftonline.com";

$headers = array(
    "POST " . $postUrl . " HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: " . $hostname,
    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
);

$access_params = array(
    "resource" => "https://graph.microsoft.com", 
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "code" => $authority,
    "client_id" => {clientid},
    "client_secret" => {secret},
    // "scope" => "offline_access calendars.readwrite",
    "scope" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    // "roles" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    "redirect_uri" => {redirecturi}
);  

$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token';

$ch = curl_init("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $access_params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: How did you implement the integration with you account to log into Outlook or OneDrive? And what detailed error message did you get when you sing in?

Comment: please share the detailed error message and incase available share the requestid, timestamp for analysis

Comment: @AllenWu please note the update.

Also, I used PHP/Curl for the integration.

Comment: @Dev please note the update.

Comment: What is the full request? Can you capture it?

Comment: @AllenWu please see update 2.

Comment: What is the real value of `$authority` in this line `"code" => $authority,`?  `code` should be the authorization_code that the app requested. It is from the response of requesting an authorization code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#successful-response. If the code is wrong, you will get the error `Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.`.

Comment: @AllenWu the $authority code are the Auth Codes shown above 
(M.R3_BAY.c531716c-c315-0c1e-7113-8805ab255856 for the first one, and M.R3_BAY.6a128cd9-cb99-ee82-eafd-2934f94aa739 for the second one.

These are obviously wrong. but that's what the auth codes always look like for these two accounts. When I authorise with the sample accounts, everything works perfectly, and I get properly formed auth codes every time.

Comment: Please share what your O365 account is like.

Comment: @AllenWu when I log in to this O365 account, the url is "https://www.office.com/?auth=1"

When I log in to any of the sample users that work, the url is "https://www.office.com/?auth=2"

Does that help?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Can you share the format of your O365 account? Is it like abc@domian.onmicrosoft.com?

Comment: @AllenWu I see what you mean. No, it's not an onmicrosoft account. I've set it up using my own domain, so it's user@domain.com.au

Comment: So you add a custom domain `domain.com.au` to the O365 tenant?

Comment: And please share the code how you get the `$authority`.

Comment: Yes, I guess so.

Comment: @AllenWu the authority token is taken from the response url by `var authority = "<?php if(!isset($_GET['code'])){echo 'nocode';}else{echo $_GET['code'];} ?>" `

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP. Did you refer to any document to write your code? If yes, please share.

Comment: @AllenWu I've been using PHP for a long time, so that bit of code came from my head, not a reference document.

Basically, it's the PHP GET request I use with JQuery to get the Auth Code that's sent back in the uri redirect after the user is authenticated.

Comment: @Sofistikat Sorry for the delay. I forgot this question:( Your code should be correct. It is the code when you are signing in with a personal account. So if you want to sign into the account as O365 user, you should specify the auth endpoint as `$postUrl = "/{your tenant id}/oauth2/token"`, not use `common`. Besides, you are using v1.0 endpoint. Don't pass `scope` in the request. Remove `"scope" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",`.

Comment: @AllenWu how do you get the user's tenant id? My app is multi-tenant, so users with personal accounts might sign in without me knowing what their tenant id is.

Comment: @Sofistikat If you want personal account to sign in, using `common` is correct. But When you use `common` endpoint, if your account is both personal account and O365 account, it will be treated only as personal account.

Comment: @AllenWu oh I see! I think I understand what you mean now. I will change the $postUrl to the tenant id of my app, and see if that works.

Comment: @Sofistikat Sure! Keep posted if possible:)

Comment: @AllenWu I tried it, but I'm still getting the strange auth codes that look like this: `M.R3_BAY.b49c6b46-e33d-b579-c9c3-e17c6cccc4f9&state=12345`

Comment: @Sofistikat `$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token';` and `$ch = curl_init("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1");` are also modified?

Comment: @AllenWu I replaced all "common" with my tenantid, and the response I got was: `array(1) {
  ["error"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(27) "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI"
    ["message"]=>
    string(47) "REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox."
  }
}`

The account I'm using to test is an Office 365 Family account. Do you know if these kinds of accounts are excluded?

Comment: @Sofistikat Generally speaking, if you can be sure that your account is an O365 account, the reason for this error is that your account does not have an Exchange online license. See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/assign-licenses-to-users?view=o365-worldwide#assign-licenses-to-one-user) to learn how to assign license. If you don't have Exchange license available, the user doesn't have a mailbox, and you can't access the mailbox using Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @AllenWu I thought this is why it was necessary to use "common" instead of the tenantid, so that users outside my tenant can use my app. So it seems that it is not possible to use the API with free or personal accounts after all.

Comment: @Sofistikat I think O365 free trial subscription should have provided some Exchange online licenses for you. You can go to O365 admin center to check it (follow the link I shared above). In fact, auth code flow can work with personal account. So I'm still not sure why you get this error:(

Comment: @AllenWu O365 Family subscription and the free version do not have Exchange licenses at all. So I guess they won't work with the API.

Comment: @Sofistikat If they don't have Exchange licenses, it is reasonable. But personal accounts should be supported.

Comment: @AllenWu that's what I thought, but my experience has been the opposite. It's so difficult to try and make sense of the complicated web Microsoft has created. But thanks for your help, I really appreciate it! :-)